# Как добавить теги найденному значению в PHP?

Tags: php

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как добавить теги найденным значениям в PHP? необходимо обернуть в тег а всех упомянутых пользователей

На входе

```html
text @user text text text @user2, @user3 text @user4 @user5!! text
```

на выходе должно быть так

```html
text <a href="#">@user</a> text text text <a href="#">@user2</a>, <a href="#">@user3</a> text <a href="#">@user4</a> <a href="#">@user5</a>!! text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в лоб:

```
$pattern = "#(@\w+)#";
$strIn = "text @user text text text @user2, @user3 text @user4 @user5!! text";
$strOut = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="#">$1</a>', $strIn);
echo $strOut . "\n";
```